# Only enable element once all input fields are filled. Reusable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I am trying to write a reusable function which loops through all input fields, if any are empty I want another element (a href or button) to be toggle a class name (disabled).

Currently it works on the first input but not the second, I think this relates to the jquery selector.

JS:

```
const toggleElem = () => {
    const parent = $('.fileUploader--videos');
    const $input = parent.find('[type="text"]'); // I think this is the issue
    const $wrapper = parent.find('.fileUploader-wrapper');
    const visibleClass = 'visible';
    $input.on('change input', () => {
        toggleElemValidInput($input, $wrapper, visibleClass);
    });
};

toggleElem();

const toggleElemValidInput = (input, elem, className) => {
    input.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        // also would prefer if ($(this).val().length !== 0)
            elem.addClass(className);
        } else {
            elem.removeClass(className);
        }
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fileUploader col fileUploader--videos hasAdvancedUpload" data-action="/api/v1/ProductMediaVideoUploadApi" data-method="post">
  <label for="videoTitle" class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="videoTitle" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Add video title" autocomplete="off">
  </label>
  <label for="videoUrl" class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="videoUrl" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Add video url" autocomplete="off">
  </label>
  <i class="fileUploader__icon fa fa-film"></i>
  <div class="fileUploader__input">
    <input class="fileUploader__file" type="file" name="file-videos" id="file-videos" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
    <label for="file-videos">Click to add a video thumbnail</label>
    <p class="fileUploader__dragndrop"> or drag it here</p>
    <ul class="small">
      <li>File formats: </li>
      <li>File size: <span class="file-size-max"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="fileUploader__uploading">Uploading...</div>
  <div class="fileUploader__success">Complete</div>
  <div class="fileUploader__error">Error. <span></span></div>
  <a href="#" class="fileUploader__restart fa fa-redo-alt"></a>
  <div class="fileUploader-wrapper mt-3 text-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">Submit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/zygw72pr/

I kind of understand creating this function and only targeting one selector, but my goal is to make it reusable and it should not matter if there is 1 input or 100.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter all the textboxes. When there are no empty ones, set the class to visible.

```
var query = "input[type=\"text\"]";

$(query).on("input change", () =>
{
  if($(query).filter((a, b) => $(b).val().length == 0).length == 0)
       $(".fileUploader-wrapper").addClass("visible");
  else
       $(".fileUploader-wrapper").removeClass("visible");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to refactor this so it can be reused. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the toggling of the class is dependent on only the last input in the collection the way you have written it in the loop like that.

You could use `filter()` to get collection of the ones that are empty (if any) and use that collection length to determine the class toggling.

Using [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with it's boolean second argument is also simpler than writing both `addClass()` and `removeClass()` in a conditional

Something like:

```
const toggleElemValidInput = (input, elem, className) => {
    const hasEmpty = !!input.filter((i,el) => !el.value.trim()).length;
    elem.toggleClass(className, hasEmpty);
};
```

Comment: Hmm, the logic makes sense (filter the selected inputs) I tried putting this into the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/zygw72pr/13/ and it does not seem to work.

Comment: Works fine in this simplified version https://jsfiddle.net/rL2tfc08/